# Laravel's Model observer class is not working when updating using query builder

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am explaining my issue with an example.

My model class is `User` and observer class is `UserObserver`.

I have added some code in the `updated` method of `UserObserver` that will run everytime the `User` model `update` function is used. For example `updated` method in the`UserObserver`(below) should get called whenever an update happen in `User` record.

```
class UserObserver{
   function updated($userModel)
   {
      //Send mail code
   }
}
```

The code in the `UserObserver` works when `User` data update like shown below:

```
User::find(2)->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);
```

However, the code in the `UserObserver` won't run when `User` data is updated in the following way:

```
User::where('id', 2)->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);
```

When I debug I can understand that `User::find(2)` return `User` model object and `User::where('id', 2)` will return a `Builder` object. So, how can I make use of our observer class method regardless of whether it is updated using `User` Model object or `Builder` object?

The issue is, I do have an existing application, some of the models are updating like `User::where('id', 2)->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);`. It is a difficult task to modify update statement to `User::find(2)->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);`.

Comment: It might be worth adding the code for the update in UserObserver in your question and the code that links the two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

`User::where('id', 2)->first()->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);`

The one problem with this code is that if you don't have the user with the `id = 2` in your database then you will get `null` and you will get and exception may be as calling update on undefined entity.

So you can avoid this as below:

`$user = User::where('id', 2)->first();
 if(!empty($user)) {
     $user->getModel()->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);
}`

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, in both cases I can able to update User information but Sending mail code in 'updated' method of the  UserObserver is not working while we update user information like User::where('id', 2)->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);

Comment: You have written this updated function in "UserObserver" model ?

Comment: No, I have an existing application, now I need to Log activity of User basically changes in Model. So if you are updating model using "Builder" object then observer function won't get called. If you are updating model using Model object then observer will get called.

Comment: Have you tried with ` $user->getModel()->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);` this statement.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have written some code in OBSERVER CLASS of USER MODEL, that will send mail when update happen to USER MODEL. In my existing application, there are lot of place where USER MODEL get updated, that is by using MODEL object and BUILDER object. Send mail code in OBSERVER CLASS is not working while USER MODEL update by builder object. I would like to use OBSERVER without changing existing application controller/model function. Kindly share your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Dear Observer not depend on Model object or Builder Object.
It works on both statements...

```
User::find(2)
```

and

```
User::where('id', 2)
```

I am facing the same problem yesterday, but i install last Monday [revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) package and when i explore that package, its work on my code `"User::where('id', 2)"`.

Actually i am placing my code in updating() method, but when i place the same code in saving() method its work for me...

Answer (score 0):

**User** model class should have a fillable variable.

```
class User extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Try to add the **first()** method after where clause.

```
User::where('id', 2)->first()->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);
```

Or twist where clause to get **User** model object.

```
$user = User::where('id', 2)->first();
if(!$user) {
     $user->update(['name'=>'Update Name']);
}
```